# Dashboards in Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

We're currently using community builder to create our community at the moment, and looking into adding dashboard components on it.

I was looking through the stackexchange forum on how to add dashboards within a community builder and hasn't found yet a definite answer.

Based from the answer on the question in the link below,Report Chart component is available in the lightning app builder but it is not currently available in community builder:

[How to insert reports/dashboards inside a lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97309/how-to-insert-reports-dashboards-inside-a-lightning-component)

> There is a Report Chart component that can be added in the lightning
>   app builder, however, it is currently not available in the community
>   builder. Docmation have a lightning component in the AppExchange which
>   can be used in the Community Builder, however it does still require
>   some code/configuration to get it working, but it will handle the
>   rendering for you. - Richard Jimenes

I've also tried installing Docmation's Lightning Chart component from appexchange but it is a managed packaged and I cannot expose it on the community builder.

Does any one have a workaround in adding dashboards on Community Builder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any unmanaged component then you can add the interface "**forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes**" and then theoretically it should just work as normal.

Other option is to build some lightning components .You can use any libraries like jqchart ,D3 ,High-charts and build the component.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Mohith, I ended up using an unmanaged package called chartJs link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5ADEAY

Looks pretty cool, but requires complex configuration in order for it to pull data from reports.